# how to determine which color highlight to use in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, abap

Somehow my eclipse has two different places setting the syntax highlight:

```
preferences
|--general 
   |--appearance
      |--colors and fonts  
         |--abap 
            |--syntax highlight

preferences
|--general 
   |--abap development
      |--editors
         |--source code editors
            |--abap keyword colors
```

The problem is that I want the second way to be the "active" syntax highlight, but Eclipse is using the first one, and I have no clue where I can switch or disable the first one.

[image]

Eclipse info:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200
```

Comment: guys, I have no idea what I did, but is using the second setting now... so it is currently working, but I don't know how. I'll leave the question opened so that anyone who knows it can still teach other people who need it

Comment: I just go the the settings path from your second way and it worked after applying, without any reloading. Maybe there was smth conflicting in your settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse by default uses the settings under *Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*, meaning it will color all keywords blue.

These settings are applied to the editor windows when opening it, meaning it is not sufficient to press the *Apply* or *Apply and Close* buttons in the *Preferences* windows, but you also need to close and reopen the editor windows for your changes to take effect.

(This might be what produced the surprising "now it suddenly works, but I don't know why" effect you observed. I assume that this is a bug and created [an internal incident](https://support.wdf.sap.corp/sap/support/message/2070360956) for this. The URL is internals only, but you can reference it in case you want to talk to somebody from SAP about it.)

The settings under *ABAP Development > Editors > Source Code Editors > ABAP Keyword Colors* allow you to override the general defaults above with more specific, ABAP-sensitive settings, meaning you can color different categories of statements differently. By default, these are all unchecked, i.e. don't apply.

These settings take effect immediately, you don't have to reopen the editor windows to apply them.

Comment: very nice! I subscribed to the incident you created, let's see what happens! thanks again :D

Comment: The issue was confirmed and processed by the ABAP Develpment Tools team. The fix should be available with one of the coming updates.

Comment: nice, I've received the notification as well, thanks!!